# Поиск в конце строки при помощи sed

Tags: sed

Подскажите что добавить в команду

```
sed -n '/\.com/p' all.txt > com.txt
```

чтобы выбрало только те строки, которые оканчиваются на .com ?

Comment: sed -n '/\.com$/p' all.txt > com.txt

Answer (score 2):

Конец строки в `sed` обозначается `$`.
То есть вам надо `sed -n '/\.com$/p' all.txt > com.txt`